# Data loss after writing in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I obtain a resultant dataframe after performing some computations over it.Say the dataframe is result. When i write it to Amazon S3 there are specific cells which are shown blank. The top 5 of my result dataframe is:

```
 
_________________________________________________________
|var30   |var31   |var32   |var33  |var34  |var35 |var36|
--------------------------------------------------------
|-0.00586|0.13821 |0       |       |1      |      |     |
|3.87635 |2.86702 |2.51963 |8      |11     |2     |14   |
|3.78279 |2.54833 |2.45881 |       |2      |      |     |
|-0.10092|0       |0       |1      |1      |3     |1    |
|8.08797 |6.14486 |5.25718 |       |5      |      |     |
---------------------------------------------------------

But when i run result.show() command i am able to see the values.

_________________________________________________________
|var30   |var31   |var32   |var33  |var34  |var35 |var36|
--------------------------------------------------------
|-0.00586|0.13821 |0       |2      |1      |1     |6    |
|3.87635 |2.86702 |2.51963 |8      |11     |2     |14   |
|3.78279 |2.54833 |2.45881 |2      |2      |2     |12   |
|-0.10092|0       |0       |1      |1      |3     |1    |
|8.08797 |6.14486 |5.25718 |20     |5      |5     |34   |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, the blank are shown in same cells every time i run it.

Comment: Great question. There are lots of details here. Makes it totally possible to understand your problem.

Comment: Please provide a [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry for that @Sa

Comment: please provide code piece that will help us to look into the problem, details what you provided are vague.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to save data to your s3
      `DataFrame.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("s3n://Yourpath")`

Comment: i using the exact same statement.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might have come across this issue, I can tell what worked for me.
I was joining 1 data frame ( let's say inputDF) with another df ( delta DF) based on some logic and storing in an output data frame (outDF). I was getting same error where by I could see a record in outDF.show() but while writing this dataFrame into a hive table OR persisting the outDF ( using outDF.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISC)) I wasn't able to see that particular record.

SOLUTION:- I persisted the inputDF ( inputDF.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISC)) before joining it with deltaDF. After that outDF.show() output was consistent with the hive table where outDF was written.

P.S:- I am not sure how this solved the issue. Would be awesome if someone could explain this, but the above worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for this issue is to refresh the data again. I encountered the same problem while writing data to a delta table using a Databricks notebook. However, once I refreshed the data, I could see my records filling in for the cells where it was showing NULL previously.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).